# How to connect GoLang with ReactNative?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, go

I have a GoLang function
Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Connect(config string) (bool, error) {
    if config == "" {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("config is not available")
    }
    return true, nil
}

func main() {}
```

How to use this function in my React Native Code?

I have tried creating the following method in my Module

```
  @ReactMethod
    public void connect(String config, Promise promise) {
        // Call the Go function and get the return values
        Object[] result = Connect(config);

        // Check the result
        if (result != null && result.length == 2) {
            boolean isConnected = (boolean) result[0];
            String message = (String) result[1];

            if (isConnected) {
                promise.resolve("");
            } else {
                promise.reject("ERROR_CODE", message);
            }
        } else {
            promise.reject("ERROR_CODE", "Invalid result from native function");
        }
    }

    private native Object[] Connect(String config);
```

But it is saying `Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_wgrn_WGRNNativeModule_Connect.`

How to resolve this?

I did `go build -o libpackage.so -buildmode=c-shared package.go`
and using

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("package");
    }
```

in the my Module.

Comment: You're calling the Go code from the Java code -- can I ask why? Do Go modules normally work in Java?

Comment: This [medium article](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) has a guide to call Go modules from Java